# how to send the userId along with post info from client side using react native?

Tags: node.js, react-native, jwt

I am currently creating a post page for my users. I am sending the title of the post along with the images from my client side to my server and it is working properly. My problem is i want to send the userId of the user who made the post also.

Here is the code i am using to send the title and images of the post.

client side code:

```
const addPost = (post)=>
const data = new FormData();

data.append("title",post.title);

post.images.forEach((image)=>
data.append("images",{
name:"image",
type:"image/jpeg",}));
```

i am using JWT to sign the token on the server side, and when i register a user it is working and the user is being added to my users table in server side. My problem is i am not able to send the userId for that user who made the post along with the title and images.

On client side, i am storing the token using expo securestore and decoding it using jwtdecode.

```
const getUser = async () => {
 const token = await getToken();
 return token ? jwtDecode(token) : null;
};
```

Comment: It depends on how the backend is structured. If the backend saves the userId in the token, you don't need to send the userId. You just need the token and the userId will be decoded from the backend. But if the backend needs the userId to be sent, It wil have to be in the body parameter the post request or in the url.

Comment: in my backend, when i do console.log(req) i can see the authToken but i dont know how to store it in my posts table, everything is getting stored except the userId. i failed to do it on the backend hence why i thought maybe the problem is in the frontend.

Comment: But when you are generating the auth token are you storing the userId in it ?

Comment: yes, i just tried a solution and it worked but i dont know why. i am sending the userId in the body of the post using the react context api, then i did this   data.append("userId", post.user.id); and in my backend when i did console.log(req.body) i got the user object which i used and was able to store the userId in the posts table. can you explain to me how it worked?

Comment: I think then, your backend endpoint requires you to pass the userId as a body parameter. it need the frontend to pass images, title, and userId. So as the frontend supplied the userId it get stored in the backend. But, It is not safe to implement this way. Cause any user that has another user id can make post request as that user.

Comment: in order to make a post the user will need to login using email and password, so only way a user can make a post as another user is if the other user gave his email and password to that user. is this safe? if not what do you suggest me to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224574/discussion-between-urchmaney-and-kd12345).

Comment: yes lets continue discussion on chat